# Learning more about glm parameters, how to dig deeper?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, interpretation

I have a Poisson distributed glm where I have identified the `origin` parameter to be significant through comparison to a nest model dropping that parameter:

```
mpoi1 = glm(count ~ marker + gene, data = somedata, family = "poisson")
mpoi2 = glm(count ~ origin + marker + gene, data = somedata, family = "poisson")

anova(mpoi1, mpoi2, test = "Chisq")

Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: count ~ marker + gene
Model 2: count ~ origin + marker + gene
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1       459     349.44                        
2       458     342.11  1    7.328 0.006789 **
```

The parameter `origin` is made up of two subcategories (free and FGT). Is there a way I can identify which of the `marker` subcategory (duplication, proximity, phylogeny and known_target) counts are affected the most by the `origin` parameter?

I though a `Welch Two Sample T-test` might suffice but none of the subcategories returned significant. I did this by running the test on a subset of the dataset to include only one `marker` subcategory such as:

```
t.test(count ~ origin, data = known)
```

Despite each returning non significant, the mean was consistently higher in the FGT `origin` subgroup for every marker subcategory.

Please feel free to ask more questions if I have not explained myself well.

Comment: Please tell us more of the real-world setting. For interpretation, try to base that on the fitted model and not separate tests! If you are interested in different `origin` effects for diferent levels of another variable, maybe consider to include an interaction in the model ...

Comment: Hi @kjetilbhalvorsen interaction as in `origin*marker`?

By real world setting do you mean the experimental design?

Comment: Yes, that is interaction! Real-world setting: Design, yes, which question do you ask from the data, ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I want to identify which counts associated sub catagories of marker are most affected by oirgin :)

Comment: There are some tools in R to help summarize and visualize fitted models. Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/vignettes/summ.html,  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/vignettes/effect_plot.html,   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntrjjNXNJCY&ab_channel=StatistikinDD  ...

Comment: and [this stored google search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk03XlYOozhk0Stshe0xDhcuWYw1Ebw%3A1595707066354&ei=uo4cX7GSFcKP0AbUg5qoCA&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+visualize+regression+model&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+visualize+regression+model&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DaQ1jofWCMkQFoAHAAeACAAXmIAZALkgEEMTkuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwix1-uGmOnqAhXCB9QKHdSBBoUQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen T=hank you for this, never really thought to just visualise it differently !